# Parse Cloud Code - Only Retrieve Certain Columns Before Sending Response.

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I currently have this cloud code to retrieve all the users that have a relation with the current user. I have to first find the current user then query the "Friends" column hence the relational query step.

The line `response.success(results)` returns all the attributes of all of the current user's friends. I only want a few of the columns that belong to these friends, not every single thing they saved when signing up.

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("getFriends", function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.UserKey;
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.ascending("updatedAt");
    query.get(userId, {
        success: function(foundCurrentUser) {
            var currentUser = foundCurrentUser;
            var relation = currentUser.relation("Friends");
            var getRelationQuery = relation.query();
            getRelationQuery.find().then(function(results) {


                response.success(results);

            });
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

I am using swift to to use the response, I am not sure that if I need to tweak the swift code but will provide it anyway.

```
func LoadCarpoolersFromParse(Success:(object:AnyObject)->(),Failure:(error:NSError)->())
{
        let params = NSMutableDictionary()
        params.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!, forKey: "UserKey")

        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getCarpoolers", withParameters: params as [NSObject : AnyObject], block: {
            (response:AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                Success(object: response!)
            }
            else{
                Failure(error:error!)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using `select` method of `Parse.Query`, make the following changes in your cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getFriends", function(request, response) {
var userId = request.params.UserKey;
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.ascending("updatedAt");
query.select("name","phone"); // replace with your required fields
```

Comment: this will be accepted but the query.select should actually be for the  getRelationQuery. So i did getRelationQuery.select("name","phone"); and it worked like a charm. thansk

Comment: i just gave an idea to you, about how to do that